# visual studio c++ library files broken/corrupted. help!

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i was replacing variable names in a large project using the replace all function.

next time i go to compile, i have 1600+ errors. they're all in library files like xlocnum, string, xdebug, stdexcept. how do I get rid of these? can these files be replaced??

```
Error   18  error C2039: 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::_DebugHeapString'   c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xlocale 343
Error   3   error C2504: 'basic_string' : base class undefined  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xdebug  110
```

Comment: You could perhaps include the text of one or more of the errors.

Comment: Please add a few, representative sample errors. We need specific information to be able to help. A good guide to SO can be found at http://tinyurl.com/sohints

Comment: Error 18 error C2039: 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::_DebugHeapString' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xlocale 343

Comment: Error 3 error C2504: 'basic_string' : base class undefined c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xdebug 110

Comment: there are hundreds more, i'm not sure that any of them individually will shed much light on the issue. i really think there is something that was inadvertently modified in these files.

Comment: Well if you just want to repair visual studio, insert the VS cd and choose repair from the setup program. Not really sure how you expect us to guess what the problem is when you won't show us all the errors (and I'm talking about cause-errors, not symptom-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you provided it looks like applied the find/replace files in "VC++ Include Directories". Go into the include directories and check the modified dates - if some of them are recent then you will need to restore them either from a backup or reinstall/repair the SDK and quite possibly Visual Studio itself.

Comment: the only one modified is xstring. could you (or some other kind soul) upload/link me to an untouched version of it please??

Comment: i think you nailed it. i ran a reverse replacement on that file and was able to fix it. thanks!!!

Comment: Groovy! Glad it was only one file.

Answer (score 1):

Without even a single error to look at, I can only assume you're linking the same libraries twice, possibly in debug and release mode at the same time. So... don't do that :)

As a general rule of thumb, when you think you found a compiler error in something as well worked on as GCC, the Microsoft C++ compiler, or their C# compiler, chances are it's *you* who's doing something wrong.

Comment: i had a functional programming before i started using the replace all function to change variable names to conform to naming conventions (boo!)

Comment: the errors are plentiful, ranging from syntax errors to missing type specifiers even after reverting to an older version (previously functional) of my project. starting a new project with just the line #include <string> produces 129 errors. i think i somehow modified these library files. i need to know if there is someway to revert to default versions

Comment: @J, and still not a single error shown. Are you getting any `C1083`?

Comment: i see lots of c2039, c2143, c2614, c4430, c2238 and others

Comment: here's a random one: Error 1755 error C2805: binary 'operator ==' has too few parameters c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\string 95

Comment: There's a missing type that's throwing off parsing of everything else, but I can't guess it from the 3 errors you posted, I need to see the entire list.

Comment: the entire list is about 240,000 characters too large. i'll have to post a link to a text file

Comment: Blah, no clue, it looks like it's trying to build concrete template versions of exceptions with `string` before including `string`, then trying to include the exception code from `string` and failing some more... Try just repairing VS.